# Redirect to relative path in different environments in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

My webapp is deployed in two environments:

1. aaa.com
2. bbb.com/myapp

How can I redirect to relative path "api/rest/document" in both environments?
The goal is when I am on bbb.com/myapp/something and I want to go to bbb.com/myapp/api/rest/document

When I try redirect with location I loose /myapp suffix and I get: bbb.com/api/rest/document.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a baseUrl constant in the app config. For each environment your base url will be different. So the idea is for you relative paths to be prepended with the baseUrl from the config.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a module where I store all my configurations of the app:

```
angular.module('myApp')

.value('config', {
    'api_url' : ((window.location.host).indexOf('aaa.com') > -1 ? 'http://aaa.com/' : 'http://bbb.com/myapp',
    'version' : '1.1.08',
});
```

In your modules you can than use `config.api_url` wherever you need. (Don't forget to inject "config" as a dependency in your modules).